# Laravel many-to-many eager loading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**My tables (Mysql):**

Actors:

```
CREATE TABLE `actors` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
);
```

Movies:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Actor_Movie:

```
CREATE TABLE `actor_movie` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `actor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `actor_movie_actor_id_foreign` (`actor_id`),
  KEY `actor_movie_movie_id_foreign` (`movie_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `actor_movie_actor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`actor_id`)  
  REFERENCES `actors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `actor_movie_movie_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) 
  REFERENCES `movies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Movie Model:

```
...
public function actors() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Actor');
}
```

Actor Model:

```
...
public function movies() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Movie');
}
```

The actual query to get movies with actors:

```
$movies = Movie::with('actors')->get();
```

The results as JSON:

```
movies: [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'movie1',
  actors: [{ id: 1, name: 'actor1' }, { id: 2, name: 'actor2' }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'movie2',
  actors: [{ id: 1, name: 'actor1' }, { id: 3, name: 'actor3' }]
}...]
```

Any solution please maybe with Laravel collections or Mysql query to get multiple movies with their actors. With the query above I get each movie with its actors but I want to get multiple movies/actors, for example, the first record will be actor1 and actor2 acting on the same movies movie1 and movie2 etc..

```
['movie1', 'movie2'] => ['actor1', 'actor2']
['movie1', 'movie3'] => ['actor1', 'actor3']
['movie4', 'movie5', 'movie6'] => ['actor4"]
etc...
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what you want the end result to be. How are you grouping them? Do you simply want all movies and all actors?

Comment: I want something like array to array, like actor1, actor2 are acting on the same movies (m1, m2) etc... with the query above return each movie with its actors...

Comment: `['movie1', 'movie2'] => ['actor1', 'actor2']` -- there is no built in way to make this, you will need to map this manually, but it will broke your speed.

Comment: Yes, I thought there is a method in Laravel, what you suggest?